# Catching thrown exceptions with an Exception class I created

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

In `GraphicsFileNotFoundException.java` all I have is an import of `FileNotFoundException` and the class `GraphicsFileNotFoundException` which extends `FileNotFoundException`.

In my main java file, I'm trying to read in a graphics file with the method `getGraphicsFile` which throws `GraphicsFileNotFoundException`.

My brain is pooped after a good 40 minutes trying to find out how to catch this exception. I've tried using a try-catch block and catching `GraphicsFileNotFoundException` but I still get the error

```
unreported exception GraphicsFileNotFoundException ; must be caught
   or declared to be thrown.



public void getGraphicsFile(String fileName) throws GraphicsFileNotFoundException {
    String graphics = "";
    Scanner getGraphics = null;
    try { 
      getGraphics = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }

    catch (GraphicsFileNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println("Error! File can't be found :/");
    }
```

Comment: Can you put an example of the code you are using to try and catch the exception "GraphicsFileNotFoundExcepetion"?. From what you explain here, I dont see any obvious problem. It could be a syntax or logical mistake in the code.

Comment: yeah hold on one second

Comment: Oh, Lol i meant in the actual question, use the code formatting tools in add it to the question. Its easier for everyone to see that way.

Comment: I'm new :( . one second

Comment: You're trying to catch `GraphicsFileNotFoundException` in a piece of code inside `getGraphicsFile` that is not throwing it (because the Scanner constructor doesn't know about your subclass at all). That's not the cause of your problem - you should show your main class that invokes `getGraphicsFile`. But it's certainly a bug. And also you don't have any code that throws a `GraphicsFileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either properly extend the `FileNotFoundException` class or manually throw an exception inside your `try` block.

Assuming this is for an assignment (I'm not sure why else you'd need to specifically extend this exception) you'll need to take another look at your `GraphicsFileNotFoundException` class and make sure that it does what it needs to.

To throw an exception, simply write your condition and the `throw` statement:

```
if(needToThrow) {
    throw new GraphicsFileNotFoundException();
}
```

To catch an exception, surround the throw statement with a `try` block immediately followed by a `catch` block.

```
try {
    // code here
    if(needToThrow) {
        throw new GraphicsFileNotFoundException();
    }
}
catch(GraphicsFileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle the error (print stack trace or error message for example)
    e.printStackTrace(); // this is printing the stack trace
}
```

I recommend using [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars2) if you aren't already because many times it will offer to surround throw statements that need to be caught with a automatically generated `try` `catch` block.

Comment: Thanks brandaemon. Just was about to start writing this. I think this is his problem. I also agree with you on eclipse.

Comment: Wow that makes a ton of sense. Thanks a ton! And yeah...I actually tried downloading Eclipse today but for some reason it couldn't find the location of Java on my computer. That's a whole other issue that I'll deal with soon enough.

Comment: @EmiliaClarke open a question, or pm me directly, id be happy to help. Eclipse is an amazing tool, almost everyone who is serious about java uses it or another ide similar like IntelliJ or NetBeans